# MYSQL SUM TWO COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, sum

I have this situation:

```
SELECT uf.*, SUM(uto.points) AS total_points_live, 
             SUM(utl.points) AS total_points_online,
             (total_points_live + total_points_online) AS total_points
FROM users AS uf    
            LEFT JOIN users_tourney_online AS uto
                ON uto.id_users = uf.id 
            LEFT JOIN users_tourney_live AS utl
                ON utl.id_users = uf.id
GROUP BY uf.id ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

But not working because aliases cannot be used.

Can you help me?

Regards,

Comment: 1 column group by may produce indeterminate columns when you select * and is illegal in most sql dialects when there are more non aggregate columns in the select clause than the group by. And there is a good chance you may trip up on this if you ever upgrade or have an environment where 'only_full_group_by' is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an alias defined in the same `SELECT` clause it is defined.

You would need to repeat the expression:

```
SUM(uto.points) + SUM(utl.points) AS total_points
```

If the `SUM`s may be `NULL`:

```
COALESCE(SUM(uto.points), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(utl.points), 0) AS total_points
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*, coalesce(total_points_live, 0) + coalesce(total_points_online, 0) total_points
FROM (
    SELECT uf.*, SUM(uto.points) AS total_points_live, SUM(utl.points) AS total_points_online
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY uf.id
) t
ORDER BY total_points desc
```

Unrelated note: `GROUP BY` and `SELECT *` do not go along well together; it is a good practice to enumerate all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause (although MySQL is somewhat lax about it).